# Dynamic SQL Projection with multiple joins in QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I was trying for dynamic sql projection with join 2 tables. here visibleColumns is the comma separated string(dynamic columns which i want to show in SQL select statement).

```
QActive qActive = QActive.active;.
QCustomer qCustomer = QCustomer.customer;
QBaseCounterParty qBaseCounterParty = QBaseCounterParty.baseCounterParty;

StringExpression path = Expressions.stringPath(qActive, visibleColumns);

return JPQLQuery<String> resultSet = query.select(path).from(qActive).innerJoin(qActive.customer, qCustomer).on(qInvoice.customer.id.eq(qCustomer.id))
            .innerJoin(qBaseCounterParty).on(qCustomer.id.eq(qBaseCounterParty.id)).where(queryDslSpec).orderBy(sort)
            .offset(request.getPagination().getStartRow()).limit(request.getPagination().getRowsPerPage());
```

so whenever i am trying to run it is creating query as below with 400 Bad Request:

```
select active.docNumber, customerName from Active active inner join Customer customer with active.id = customer.id inner join BaseCounterParty baseCounterParty with customer.id = baseCounterParty.id order by active.transactionDate desc
```

I am not sure how to select columns from other tables as columns are totally coming as dynamic.

Comment: You can't fetch columns from a String. This is not how QueryDSL works. You have to match your columns with the Q type, and pass an Array of these Qtypes to the SELECT.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Can you please show me how to do that with code.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I need to select dynamic columns but not sure how to match columns from Qtype as it is dynamic so I would not be knowing which column can come.

Comment: `.select(qCustomer.name, qBaseCounterParty.whatever, ...)`. The fetch will return a Tuple object, then you can do `tuple.get(qCustomer.name)`

Comment: @GuillaumeF. In select statement, I don't know which columns UI will send and UI actually send a list of columns so how can i select and there is join also there between tables so don't know which column is coming from which table so to get QType of that column is difficult

Comment: This question is way too broad for StackOverflow. I gave you the technical answer to your original question, now you have to find a way to implement it yourself. Write tests, find ways, that's the developer's job.

Answer (score 2):

Here some example of using QueryDSL constructor projection, to fill with data any dto.
Warning dto constructor must have same parameters type and etc.

```
QActive qActive = QActive.active;.
QCustomer qCustomer = QCustomer.customer;
QBaseCounterParty qBaseCounterParty = QBaseCounterParty.baseCounterParty;

return JPQLQuery<SomeDTO> resultSet =  query.select(Projections.constructor(SomeDTO.class, 
                    qActive.someValue1,
                    qBaseCounterParty.someValue2,
                    qActive.someValue3))
        .from(qActive)
        .innerJoin(qActive.customer, qCustomer).on(qInvoice.customer.id.eq(qCustomer.id))
        .innerJoin(qBaseCounterParty).on(qCustomer.id.eq(qBaseCounterParty.id))
        .where(queryDslSpec)
        .orderBy(sort)
        .offset(request.getPagination().getStartRow()).limit(request.getPagination().getRowsPerPage());

public class SomeDTO {

// QueryDSL Constructor
public SomeDTO(String value1, int value2, String value3) {
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
    this.value3 = value3;
}
```

}

Comment: In query.select() you are passing the columns which you know. My question is I need to select dynamic projection then how can I select dynamic projection.

Comment: @Deepak ok. Lets try to use json map. So u can store anything and fetch it as u need (string or map etc).